# PictureBox.Invalidate not re-rendering correctly

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to build a little test application (and my WinForm skills have rusted somewhat) with an Image and some overlays on top of it.

[image: Example]

My image is set to stretch in the PictureBox but my fields on the right hand side I want to be from the origin of the image. Therefore I decided to render directly on the image that the PictureBox is using to ensure that the co-ordinates are always correct. Here's the white box rendering:

```
  private void pbImage_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (this.rdFront.Checked)
                RenderFront(pbImage.Image, true);
            else
                RenderBack(pbImage.Image, true);

        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
        { }
    }

public void RenderFront(Image image, bool includeBoxes)
    {
        // If we have no image then we can't render
        if (image == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("image");

        Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(image);

        // Get the top label
        foreach (MessageConfiguration config in this.config.Values.Where(c => c.Front))
        {
            if (includeBoxes)
            {
                // Fill a White rectangle and then surround with a black border
                gfx.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, config.X, config.Y, config.Width, config.Height);
                gfx.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, config.X - 1, config.Y - 1, config.Width + 2, config.Height + 2);
            }

            gfx.DrawString(config.Text, new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, config.FontSize), Brushes.Black, new PointF(config.X, config.Y));
        }
    }
```

The problem that I've got is if I do this and always draw on the underlying image then when I move the white overlay, I end up with un-drawn parts of the image. So I decided to clone the image before each re-render (on the basis that I don't care about performance).

I therefore decided to clone the image whenever I need to manually invalidate it, and call this when a setting changes:

```
    public void Refresh()
    {
        if (this.rdFront.Checked)
            pbImage.Image = new Bitmap(front);
        else
            pbImage.Image = new Bitmap(back);

        this.pbImage.Invalidate();
    }
```

Now I'm sure I must be missing something obvious - if I modify one of the values my penguins render with no overlay. However if I force a resize of the application then both the penguins and the overlay suddenly appear.

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

**Edit**

Here's a download link to the project as it's quite small. Paste a path to an image in the 'Front Image' box and try using the controls on the right (set 100x100 height and width). Try re-sizing to see the desired affect.  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41796243/TemplateTester.zip

Comment: I really don't understand the question fully. Sorry for that. But, why don't you directly paint to `PictureBox`? Ok, if at all you decided to paint in `Image` then you need to paint it once, cache the image and show it. You need to invalidate the cache whenever you're updating the values. Also am not sure where does `front` and `back` in `Refresh` method comes from.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Front/Back just because I've got 2 images I can toggle. The problem with painting straight to the PictureBox is co-ordinate 0,0 might not be on the image (because the PictureBox has zoomed and centered), whereas on the image it will.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: I've added a download link to the project - thought it might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controls and Forms have a `Refresh` method already. Are you really calling **your** `Refresh` method? Aren't you getting a warning that you should use the `new` keyword? Better give your `Refresh` method another name (e.g `RefreshImage`)!

---

I'm really not sure why you are using a picture box but then decide to do your on painting. I suggest to draw to an image off-screen and then simply assign it to the picture box:

```
public void RefreshImage()
{
    Bitmap bmp;
    if (this.rdFront.Checked)
        bmp = new Bitmap(front);
    else
        bmp = new Bitmap(back);

    using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
        foreach (MessageConfiguration config in this.config.Values.Where(c => c.Front))
        {
            if (includeBoxes) {
                // Fill a White rectangle and then surround with a black border
                gfx.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, config.X, config.Y, config.Width, config.Height);
                gfx.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, config.X - 1, config.Y - 1, config.Width + 2, config.Height + 2);
            }
            gfx.DrawString(config.Text, new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, config.FontSize), Brushes.Black, new PointF(config.X, config.Y));
        }
    }

    pbImage.Image = bmp;
}
```

and remove the `pbImage_Paint` method.

---

Another possibility is to use the `pbImage_Paint` event handler in another way. Call the `base.Paint()` handler of the picture box that draws the image but leave the image itself unchanged. Instead draw on top of it by using the `Graphics` object given by the `PaintEventArgs e` argument. This Graphics object represents the client area of the picture box. This does not alter the Bitmap assigned to the picture box, but only draws on the screen.

```
private void pbImage_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.Paint(); // Paints the image
    if (this.rdFront.Checked)
        RenderFront(e.Graphics, true);
    else
        RenderBack(e.Graphics, true);
}

public void RenderFront(Graphics g, bool includeBoxes)
{
    foreach (MessageConfiguration config in this.config.Values.Where(c => c.Front)) {
        if (includeBoxes) {
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, config.X, config.Y, config.Width, config.Height);
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, config.X - 1, config.Y - 1, config.Width + 2, config.Height + 2);
        }
        g.DrawString(config.Text, new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, config.FontSize), Brushes.Black, new PointF(config.X, config.Y));
    }
}
```

Comment: That's true - but isn't the problem.